# How do I write a Cairo surface to png to stdout?

Tags: c++, linux, cgi, cairo

I'm trying to write a CGI program that will output a PNG image to stdout. I can already do this from an image file (PNG or otherwise), but now I'm using Cairo to dynamically generate some image, then output it to the browser.

The problem I'm facing is this: the way Cairo writes a surface to a PNG is using one of two functions. The first is Surface::write_to_png(string filename). This doesn't work for me, since I'm not writing to a file, but to stdout. The second is Surface::write_to_png_stream( something-or-other write_func), as described [here](http://cairographics.org/documentation/cairomm/reference/classCairo_1_1Surface.html#ab3eca5bc13abe27f470fdf08134269bb). I do not understand how this works, or even if this is what I want. Is there a better way to accomplish this, and if not, how do I use this abysmal function?

Thanks

Comment: So, what's up, is it working?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Hey I just saw your comment today, sorry about that. Anyway, yes I got it working, I wrote an answer on the bottom there. Thanks!

Comment: Note: The write-func argument is really a sigc::slot, which is something called a "delegate", ie. you could also create a slot from an object and one of its member functions, not just a plain C function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the documentation, write a function to handle the writing:

```
#include <cstdio> // for stdout

Cairo::ErrorStatus my_write_func(unsigned char* data, unsigned int length)
{
  return length == std::fwrite(data, length, stdout) ? CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS : CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR;
}
```

Usage:

```
my_surface.write_to_png_stream(my_write_func);
```

Comment: Well, what's an 'ErrorStatus'?

Comment: It's a type that Cairo defines. Check the docs. It should just work if you write it like that, though.

Comment: No, it doesn't. That's what I thought too, but the compiler specifically complains about it, saying "'ErrorStatus' does not name a type". Everything else from Cairo works, however.

Comment: Maybe the class or namespace is missing, as I said, check the docs. It's definitely a type. I can do it for you if you really want me to. Have you tried `Cairo::ErrorStatus`?

Comment: @Hassan: Yes, it's definitely `Cairo::ErrorStatus`. Edited.

Comment: Yes, it is Cairo::ErrorStatus. However, the code doesn't work. I would try to fix it, but I don't fully understand it. I also don't understand why I couldn't just give it a stream or file descriptor to write to, instead of the file. Anyway, I'll keep trying, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need the answer to this question(if you exist), I've figured it out:

Kerrek actually gets most of the credit here, but I thought I would post my results, and what ended up working. Here's the write function:

```
Cairo::ErrorStatus write_stdout(const unsigned char* data, unsigned int length)
{
return std::cout.write((char*)data,length)?CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS:CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR;
}
```

Now, I don't know whether this will return CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR on error, since I'm not sure what the return value of `write` is. However, this code does work.

To call it, I used:

```
surface->write_to_png_stream(&write_stdout);
```

`surface` was defined as such:

```
Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::ImageSurface> surface =
Cairo::ImageSurface::create(Cairo::FORMAT_ARGB32, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Basically, it's a normal surface. Anyways, thanks to Kerrek again, for answering, and I hope that helps someone.

Comment: Oh OK, the surface is a pointer. Cool. In my version I test whether `cout::write` returns the actual length that we meant to write, because it's supposed to return the number of bytes written. In your case, you only check if you write *at least one byte*. I guess it'll work most of the time, though.